# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error when parsing json

Tags: scala

For this class

```
case class AnswerOfAPracticeQuestion (question_id: UUID, 
                                      image: Option[List[String]], 
                                      notes: Option[String],
                                      answer:List[AnswerSection],
                                      answer_id:Option[UUID],
                                      answeredBy: Option[Answerer],
                                      creationYear:Option[Long],
                                      creationMonth:Option[Long],
                                     ){
}
```

the `Reads` method fails when I send this `json` to it

```
{
   "new-answer":{
      "images":[
         "image 1",
         "image 2"
      ],
      "notes":"some notes",
      "answer":[
         {
            "filename":"f1",
            "answer":"a1"
         },
         {
            "filename":"f2",
            "answer":"a2"
         }
      ],
      "answer-id":"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112",
      "question-id":"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "creator-id":"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113"
   }
}
```

`Reads` method is

```
  implicit val answerOfAPracticeQuestionReads: Reads[AnswerOfAPracticeQuestion] = (
      (JsPath \ "question-id").read[UUID] and
      (JsPath \ "images").readNullable[List[String]] and 
      (JsPath \ "notes").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "answer").read[List[AnswerSection]] and //FAILS FOR THIS LINE
      (JsPath \ "answer-id").readNullable[UUID] and
      (JsPath \ "answerer").readNullable[Answerer] and
      (JsPath \ "creation-year").readNullable[Long] and //year/month are for internal consumption so not worried about receiving it from a client
      (JsPath \ "creation-month").readNullable[Long]
    )(AnswerOfAPracticeQuestion.apply _)
```

`Reads` for `AnswerSection` is

```
implicit val answerSectionReads:Reads[AnswerSection] = (
    (JsPath \ "filename").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "answer").read[String]
    )(AnswerSection.apply _)
```

The error is

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at models.AnswerImplicits$.<init>(Answers.scala:92)
    at models.AnswerImplicits$.<clinit>(Answers.scala)
    at models.AnswerImplicits$AnswerAPIReads$.reads(Answers.scala:108)
    at play.api.libs.json.ConstraintReads.$anonfun$optionWithNull$1(JsConstraints.scala:110)
    at play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:132)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult.validateOpt(JsLookup.scala:164)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult.validateOpt$(JsLookup.scala:162)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsDefined.validateOpt(JsLookup.scala:176)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue.validateOpt(JsValue.scala:20)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue.validateOpt$(JsValue.scala:19)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsObject.validateOpt(JsValue.scala:124)
    at controllers.AnswerController.$anonfun$newAnswer$1(AnswerController.scala:399)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.SecuredActionBuilder.$anonfun$invokeBlock$8(SecuredAction.scala:216)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.SecuredRequestHandlerBuilder.$anonfun$invokeBlock$2(SecuredAction.scala:93)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.RequestHandlerBuilder.handleInitializedAuthenticator(RequestHandler.scala:169)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.RequestHandlerBuilder.handleBlock(RequestHandler.scala:119)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.RequestHandlerBuilder.handleBlock$(RequestHandler.scala:117)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.SecuredRequestHandlerBuilder.handleBlock(SecuredAction.scala:52)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.actions.SecuredRequestHandlerBuilder.$anonfun$invokeBlock$1(SecuredAction.scala:93)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:302)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1021)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.execLocalTasks(ForkJoinPool.java:1046)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: scala.UninitializedFieldError: Uninitialized field: C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\app\models\Answers.scala: 196
    at models.AnswerImplicits$.answerOfAPracticeQuestionWrites(Answers.scala:196)
    at models.PracticeQuestionImplicits$.<init>(PracticeQuestion.scala:139)
    at models.PracticeQuestionImplicits$.<clinit>(PracticeQuestion.scala)
    ... 29 more


Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]
...
```

If I compare the `implicit` methods, in the pics below, you'll notice that the `reads`, there is an additional `canBuildForm` while there is nothing like it in `writes`

Reads
[image]

Writes
[image]

Comment: Nothing specific to Play/JSON there, but to Scala init order. Replace `val` by `def` or `lazy val`, or make sure the implicit are defined in the order they will have to be loaded

Comment: thanks. `lazy` stuff didn't work. I'll change the order. How does the order matter btw?

Comment: early days but the order seem to have made the difference. Earlier the `implicits` were defined in separate file/object and I was importing them. Now I moved them in the same file and things seem to have progressed. But why does the order matter?

Comment: thanks. things are working now after changing the order. Happy to except you answer. Could you also please explain what was the mistake

Comment: @ManuChadha Scala executes the contents of any block (even class definitions!) from top to bottom, so e.g. `{ val x = y; val y = 1; }` won't work, since the definition of `x` is trying to use `y`, which hasn't been defined yet. If we haven't defined our desired implicit, then we may fall back to a different one. We can use `lazy` and `def` to define things without evaluating them yet, e.g. the above will work with `lazy val x = y`. However, this allows infinite loops, e.g. `{ lazy val x = y; lazy val y = x; }`.